# Magento multi select layered navigation

Tags: collection, layered-navigation, filtered-nav

How to implement multi select (checkbox) layered navigation?

I want to be able to filter by multiple attributes like sub categories eg:

```
cat=2,3,4 

&

color=green,red
```